# javascript bundles in ASP.NET Core MVC not being served on IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC Core app in Visual Studio which references bootstrap files in the wwwroot folder:

```
  /wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js
```

When I run the site in using IIS Express it return the file using this URL:

```
http://example.com/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

I am now deploying the site to IIS and this URL no longer works and returns a 404. I have configured the program to start with IIS Integration:

```
                     webBuilder
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseIISIntegration()
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

What am I missing?

The "Identity" part of the URL comes from Identity Server 4, so it could be that the bootstrap.bundle.min.js file is come from this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your asset files as shown below and publish the app to the server:

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js" >
```

change to

```
<link href="./lib/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js" >
```

***Update:*** If some of the files cannot be published to the server, check this:

Select the file(s) that is not published to server and go to properties (click F4) of the file under properties, check the properties set for it:

***Build Action:*** Content

***Copy to Output Directory:*** Do not copy then publish it

Comment: Test this and it does not solve the problem. The URL generated on my local machine includes the word "bundle" in the file name and correctly servers the file, despite the file not having "bundle" in the name. On IIS this doesn't work.

Comment: I have added more information to question about identity servers.

Comment: I think there is not such a file on `http://example.com/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`, is that true?

Comment: It isn't on disk, it just seems to appear by magic. Additiionaly in IIS I can't get the /Identity area to resolve any files from wwwroot in IIS.

Comment: Identity folder/location seems to be redundant and there would be lib folder in the app root I think.

Comment: I went with renaming them to the non bundle as you suggested. I still have no idea how the bundled version was being created locally.